# How to change reply to address if using smtp auth in Exim mail server

Tags: linux, exim

If I use smtp auth for send mail on mail client , the reply-to address received by destination is the same used in smtp authentication. 
I must authenticate with the same . It is forced by exim config. it's possible to change?

my config is :

POP3: mail.xxx.xxx user:abc@xxxx.xxx

SMTP: mail.xxxx.xxx auth with user:xyz@xxxx.xxx

the destination reply-to address is abc@xxxx.xxx but I want xyz@xxxx.xxx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your email composer should allow you to add a `Reply-to` header.  This is different from the `From` header which should match the user you authenticate as.  Alternatively, setting a `Sender` header to the user you are authenticating as should allow you to use a different `From` header.  Either the `Sender` or `From` address should match the envelope from address.

It would be best to leave your Exim configuration alone. You will have the least delivery problems if when you compose the message you either:

- add `Sender:` header with the address you are using to authenticate and set the `From:` address to the address that should receive replies; or
- add a 'Reply-To:` header with the address that you want to receive replies and set the From address to the address you are authenticating with.

Exim will enforce the `Sender` header rules if `local_from_check` is true (default).   Related settings include `local_from_prefix`, `local_from_prefix`, `qualify_domain` and `untrusted_set_sender`.  You should be able to avoid the fixups if you authenticate with a user listed in `trusted_users` or belonging to one of the `trusted_groups`.  It is also possible to conditionally bypass the fixup with the `suppress_local_fixups` flag.  The Sender line processing is documented in the [Exim Specification](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/index.html)

If you want to risk delivery issues, you can modify your Exim configuration to not ensure you have the correct headers.  The simplest option is to add a line to the top of your Exim configuration reading:

```
untrusted_set_sender=false
```

Comment: Thank you Bill, but could you please let me know ( in simple words) what changes in the Exim configuration will help me to achieve this.

Comment: @Rinshad I've updated the answer.  If you change your Exim configuration it is likely your mail will be treated as Spam..  Fix the issue in your email composer.